# How do I communicate that a generic type with a reference in it only needs to live through a function call?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I have two structures, one of which has a type parameter that is set to a reference to another.  When I take that reference as an argument in a function, I don't know how to signal that the lifetime should not become dependent.

I've trimmed it down to this example:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<T> {
    bar_type: PhantomData<T>,
}

struct Bar {}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn takebar(&mut self, bar: T) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo: Foo<&Bar> = Foo {
        bar_type: PhantomData,
    };
    let bar = Bar {};

    foo.takebar(&bar);
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `bar` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:18
   |
19 |     foo.takebar(&bar);
   |                  ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
20 | }
   | - `bar` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

I understand that `foo` needs to live as long as `bar` here, so I can "resolve" this by declaring `bar` before `foo` to reverse their destruction order.

This won't work for my situation, and more importantly, I'm not sure why it's happening or how to avoid it.  I've tried all sorts of explicit lifetime setups and none of them seem to resolve the problem.  If I turn `takebar(&mut self, ...` into `takebar(&self, ...`, it also works, but I can't always do that. It also works if I move the type parameter to the function from the struct, but again, can't always do that.

How do I communicate that the `&bar` reference should not be tied into `foo`'s lifetime, and only actually needs to live through the function call?

Comment: [This users.rust-lang.org post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/expressing-hrtb-like-bound-on-generic-struct/18081) is remarkably similar.

Comment: @trentcl That is almost exactly my issue (in my situation, it's essentially a serializing map, which serializes values inbound and deserializes them again on retrieval, so pretty much the same in a lot of ways).  I just didn't know how to find it.  That's incredibly useful information, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

A simpler reproduction:

```
struct Foo<T>(Option<T>);
struct Bar;

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn takebar(&mut self, bar: T) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo: Foo<&Bar> = Foo(None);
    let bar = Bar;

    foo.takebar(&bar);
}
```

The compiler only cares about the function signature. One *possible* implementation of `takebar` with the existing function signature is one which stores it:

```
fn takebar(&mut self, bar: T) {
    self.0 = Some(bar)
}
```

Thus, the example code must be prevented from compiling.

Normally, I'd advocate for putting another type parameter on the function and expressing the operations that you need to do, but you've already ruled that out:

```
fn takebar<T2>(&mut self, bar: T2)
where
    T2: PartialEq<T>,
{
    self.0.take();
}
```

> If I turn `takebar(&mut self, ...` into `takebar(&self, ...`, it also works

Yes, because you cannot store the value then (unless you add interior mutability, in which case the error comes back).

See also:

- [Is it possible to have a struct which contains a reference to a value which has a shorter lifetime than the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45713314/155423)

Comment: Hmm.  I thought I might be able to use explicit lifetimes or something of the sort to tell the compiler that bar needs to be the same type, but doesn't need to live as long because no references to it are kept.  If that's impossible, I suppose I just need to try to find a better way to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Taywee the lifetime is  *part of the type*, they aren't distinct.

Comment: Ah, there we go, that makes it really click.  Thank you so much for that.  I'll see if I can refactor this to make it work.