# How do I pass a function that creates a struct containing a Cell with a lifetime to another function?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to pass a constructor function as an argument to another function. The function creates a struct with an associated lifetime.  I need to create a struct from this pointer **after** I have created some other objects that this struct can then reference. The example below seems to work:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    number: Option<&'a usize>,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { number: None }
    }
}

fn foo<'a, F>(func: &F)
where
    F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
{
    let number = 42;
    let mut bar = (func)();
    bar.number = Some(&number);
}

fn main() {
    foo(&Bar::new);
}
```

When I add a `Cell` for interior mutability then it does not compile:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Bar<'a> {
    number: Cell<Option<&'a usize>>,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar {
            number: Cell::new(None),
        }
    }
}

fn foo<'a, F>(func: &F)
where
    F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
{
    let number = 42;
    let bar = (func)();
    bar.number.set(Some(&number));
}

fn main() {
    foo(&Bar::new);
}
```

Giving me the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `number` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:26
   |
21 |     bar.number.set(Some(&number));
   |                          ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
22 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 15:1...
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
15 | / fn foo<'a, F>(func: &F)
16 | | where
17 | |     F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
18 | | {
...  |
21 | |     bar.number.set(Some(&number));
22 | | }
   | |_^
```

Why did the first example work and not the second? Is there a way to specify a lifetime that exists for the scope `let mut bar` until the end of the function, rather than `'a` which encompasses the entire function? Is this not possible without Non Lexical Lifetimes or Higher Kind Type Constructors etc?

Comment: This looks like a bug, related to some special handling of `Cell` by the compiler. See [this playground snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ea79b3576a84f620cdf0c4b5e3bf52a8&version=stable&mode=debug) where I've replaced the `std::cell::Cell` with a custom type having exactly the same constraints, but it doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: Very interesting... so the lifetime definition as I've written it does match what I was attempting in your opinion? In which case if there aren't any any other answers I shall file a bug report. Exciting!
@PeterHall would like to add your comment as an answer?

Comment: A thing to note — those aren't function pointers. A function pointer is of type `fn(...) -> ...`. You just have generic types that implement the `Fn*` traits (which don't have a succinct name AFAIK). You also don't need to take a reference to it, just pass it by value.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is smarter than you give it credit for. It has **prevented you from introducing memory unsafety**:

> ```
> fn foo<'a, F>(func: &F)
> where
>     F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
> {
>     let number = 42;
>     let bar = (func)();
>     bar.number.set(Some(&number));
> }
> ```

This code says that the caller of `foo` can specify a lifetime for `'a`, but then the body of the method stores a reference into the value. That stored reference is not guaranteed to live that long. As an obvious example, the caller might require that `'a` == `'static`, but that would be impossible for the function to accomplish:

```
fn b() -> Bar<'static> {
    Bar {
        number: Cell::new(None),
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(&b);
}
```

Note that this doesn't have anything to do with closures or functions:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let number = Cell::new(None);
    let x = 1;
    number.set(Some(&x));
    let y = 2;
    number.set(Some(&y));
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |     number.set(Some(&x));
  |                      ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
9 | }
  | - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

> Why did the first example work and not the second?

Because the compiler knows that `Cell` (really `UnsafeCell`) needs to account for the possibility that you will be storing a value in the created type.

From [the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance), emphasis mine:

> - `UnsafeCell<T>`, `Cell<T>`, `RefCell<T>`, `Mutex<T>` and all other interior mutability types are **invariant over `T`** (as is `*mut T` by metaphor)

[Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) is a dense topic that I cannot explain succinctly.

[@trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3650362/trentcl) provides this example that shows that your original code may not be doing what you think it is.

Without the `Cell`, the compiler knows that it's safe to automatically adjust the lifetime of the returned type to one that's a little bit shorter. If we force the type to be the longer `'a`, however, we get the same error:

```
fn foo<'a, F>(func: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
{
    let number = 42;
    let mut bar: Bar<'a> = func();
    //           ^^^^^^^
    bar.number = Some(&number);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `number` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:24
   |
17 |     bar.number = Some(&number);
   |                        ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 11:1...
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | / fn foo<'a, F>(func: F)
12 | | where
13 | |     F: Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
14 | | {
...  |
17 | |     bar.number = Some(&number);
18 | | }
   | |_^
```

> Is this not possible without [...]

Yes, but I'm not sure exactly what it would be. I believe it would need [generic associated types (GAT) from RFC 1598](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md).

My first thought was to try higher-ranked trait bounds (HRTB):

```
fn foo<F>(func: F)
where
    F: for<'a> Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
{
    let number = 42;
    let bar = func();
    bar.number.set(Some(&number));
}
```

This triggers [E0582](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0582):

```
error[E0582]: binding for associated type `Output` references lifetime `'a`, which does not appear in the trait input types
  --> src/main.rs:17:25
   |
17 |     F: for <'a> Fn() -> Bar<'a>,
   |                         ^^^^^^^
```

---

To be honest, I cannot see the value in the code based on the example provided. If you are returning a `Bar` by value, you can make it mutable, removing any need for interior mutability.

You can also change the closure to take the value as needed:

```
fn foo<F>(func: F)
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> Bar<'a>,
{
    let number = 42;
    let bar = func(&number);
}
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to have a struct which contains a reference to a value which has a shorter lifetime than the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45713314/155423)
- [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423)

Comment: But in the first example, surely my reference to `number` also does not exists for the lifetime of `'a` (i.e. the entire function and possibly beyond)? Why does that one compile?

Comment: What exactly does invariant over T mean in this context?

Comment: Is there no way to say "infer the lifetime `'a` at the point where function `func` is called, not where the function `foo` is called"?

Comment: To address the final point in your question @Shepmaster, it is a slightly contrived example. For reasons outside the scope of this question the struct needs to be immutable - I was seeking to create a minimum example that demonstrated my issue with out cluttering it. I think I might open another question to better rephrase what I'm getting at, perhaps with a larger example.

Comment: @Drgabble yep, I figured it was an artifact of the example.

Comment: Ooh, that final example might actually work with what I was looking for... I had originally tried it without the `&'a i32` and got the error `binding for associated type \`Output\` references lifetime \`'a\`, which does not appear in the trait input types`. But I could change it to take the input.

Comment: I'd like to see an explanation of the mechanism by which the compiler treats `Cell` differently from an apparently identical user-defined struct. The type of `Cell` does not communicate the invariance.