# Why does this value not live long enough?

Tags: rust, lifetime, lexical-scope, borrowing

I don't understand why I am getting the following compiler error from this code:

```
struct Superhero<'a> { name: &'a String, power: &'a i32 } //  1    
                                                          //  2    
fn main() {                                               //  3    
    let n = "Bruce Wayne".to_string();                    //  4    
    let r;                                                //  5    
    {                                                     //  6    
        let p = 98;                                       //  7    
        {                                                 //  8    
            let hero = Superhero{ name: &n, power: &p };  //  9    
            r = hero.name;                                // 10    
        }                                                 // 11    
        println!("{}", r);                                // 12    
    }                                                     // 13    
}                                                         // 14
```

Compiler Error: `rustc 1.27.1 (5f2b325f6 2018-07-07)`

```
error[E0597]: `p` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:9:53
   |
9  |             let hero = Superhero{ name: &n, power: &p };
   |                                                     ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
13 |     }
   |     - `p` dropped here while still borrowed
14 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

Here is what I thought this code would do, line by line. There is something wrong with one or more of these lines, because this code does not compile.

```
 4: Initialize name: String to "Bruce Wayne".to_string();
 5: Declare r to be initialized in a different scope
 6: Begin a new scope (A)
 7: Initialize p to 98
 8: Begin a new scope (B)
 9: Initialize hero: Superhero to a new struct
       hero.name refers to the variable{n},
       hero.power refers to the variable{p}  
10: Copy a reference to the variable{n}, 
       since reference types are copy, both hero.name and r are distinct references to the variable{n}.
11: End scope (B): hero and the two references it owns {hero.name, hero.power} are dropped.
12: Print the value of the variable{r}: Should print "Bruce Wayne"
13: End scope (A): the variable{p} is dropped.
14: End scope for main. The variables {n, r} are dropped.
```

Why does the compiler error say that something is still borrowing `p` on line 13? Shouldn't `hero` (and subsequently `hero.power`) have been dropped on line 11? There should be nothing referring to `p` at this point.

Curiously, changing the order in which the values (`p` and `r`) are initialized  fixes the issue, and I have no idea why.

Ways to fix:

1. Move line 7 `let p = 90;` between line 4 and line 5
2. Move line 5 `let r;` between line 7 and line 8

In both of these cases, simply declaring `r` AFTER `p` ensures that nothing is still "borrowing" `p` when it is dropped. This makes no sense to me at all, because I feel like `r` has nothing at all to do with `p`, or with anything that may be borrowing `p`.

This code [runs with non-lexical lifetimes enabled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ceafedff06064ea2630de9adf86433ae&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015).

What property of lexical lifetimes causes this to not compile, and what about non-lexical lifetimes fixes this issue?

Comment: [Works with non-lexical lifetimes enabled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ceafedff06064ea2630de9adf86433ae&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: I feel like there is a close duplicate for this but I'm not finding any good ones. [Is it possible to have a struct which contains a reference to a value which has a shorter lifetime than the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713314/is-it-possible-to-have-a-struct-which-contains-a-reference-to-a-value-which-has) is similar.

Comment: Awesome @trentcl I had not heard of non-lexical lifetimes before now. I have only been doing Rust for about two weeks.

I would love to know more about what exactly about lexical lifetimes causes this error, and what property of non-lexical lifetimes fixes it. It still does not make sense to me why the initialization order of p and r has anything to do with values that borrow p.

Comment: See also: [When is it useful to define multiple lifetimes in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29861388/155423).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a guess, but here is what I think happens:

- When you declared `Superhero`, you stated that `name` and `power` should have the same lifetime.
- The type for `r` is inferred as `&String` (or maybe `&str`, the point is that `r` is a reference). With lexical lifetimes, `r` must live until the end of the block in which it is declared, so until line 14.
- Since you affect `hero.name` to `r`, `hero.name` should live at least as long as `r`, therefore `hero.name` should live until line 14.
- Since `hero.name` and `hero.power` should have the same lifetime per the struct declaration, `hero.power` should also live until line 14.
- Since `hero.power` borrows `p`, `p` should live until line 14, but it only lives until the end of the block in which it is declared (line 13).

The reason it works with non-lexical lifetimes is because the compiler notices that you don't use `r` after line 12 and is therefore able to shorten the lifetimes accordingly. Note that [it doesn't work even with nll if you use `r` after the closing brace of line 13](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eb7d86734b41a69b23f14164311c9049&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: Thanks, Jmb. This is useful. I feel like what you said makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=48362cfc5ee81ff07628f9b60477c4cb&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015

this is another way to fix it. The lifetime of 'power' and 'name' in your struct is the same (&'a). So when 'power' goes out of scope, the compiler will think that 'name' is also out of scope. So you need to define another lifetime for your struct